# direction in build a block feature for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have built a self destructing messaging app with **Parse.com** and now i want to create a blocking feature to stop any unwanted messages from people i do not want messaging me.

what i already have:

```
 NSString *usernameBlock = [self.blockUser.text]; 

  PFUser *blockedUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    [blockedUser addObject:usernameBlock forKey:@"blockedUsers"];
    PFRelation *blockedRelation = [blockedUser relationForKey:@"bUser"];
    [blockedRelation addObject:blockedUser];
    [blockedUser saveInBackground];
```

in my inbox i have:

```
if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Messages"];
    [query whereKey:@"recipientIds" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
```

if i block the user by typing in their username and pressing block i want to add the user to a block list. and then that users messages do not get to my inbox.

what would be the best way to block blocked users messages and how can i do it? also i would like to display an array of the blocked users. how can i query the blocked users to display them in table view?

if you see recipientIds are objectIds and we type usernames which are store as array of usernames, so how can i block a user?

Please help?

[image: users class with the relation and blockedUser array]

[image: user relation with blockedUser it displays the user who blocked the user in blockedUser array]

[image]

1st image: users class with the blocked relation and blockedUser array containing senderNames

2nd image: user relation with blockedUser it displays the user who blocked the user in blockedUser array

3rd image: Messages class where the message uploads within the class i have @"senderName" @"senderId" for the user who sends the message and @"recipientId" for user who receives the message,

Comment: You've already answered your question. _add the user to a block list_ you can do this many ways, but ultimately you know your project so you will have to do what best suits your project. One of the easiest ways i personally think would just create an Array column type in parse backend User class and add the blocked user to the current users array.

Comment: @soulshined how would i block that users messages would i hide any messages they send? how would i do that?

Comment: You _can_ block them, I think it just makes more sense to simply omit them using a query, something like: `whereKey:notEqualTo`

Comment: @soulshined I did pfquery of usernames equal to the username typed in in the block field and when I block them I want their messages to not come to my inbox

Comment: Can you update the question with the data model that you have and the code that you have which tries to exclude blocked users.  Otherwise we're just having a chat in a chat room about a vague idea.

Comment: @danh see question above

Comment: Please describe the relevant objects, like the Message object and how it relates to User.

Comment: so message is all the messages retrieved relating to that users username and displayed in the inbox.

Comment: Do you mean that there's an object called Message and it has a column called author and that's a string column containing the username of the sender of the message?

Comment: @soulshined i have edited the above question, how can i implement the `whereKey:notEqualTo` successfully?

Comment: @smithyy my answer would have been close to identical to dahns. I upvoted his because it's a great answer

Comment: @soulshined I'm trying to get it to work but I'm having difficulty so I'm waiting for dahn to reply but if you could help and point me in the direction in getting it to work I have posted addition info requested by dahn also. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: I'm just not sure it is what you want @smithyy or how to help. there are a lot of directions with your question. Based on your first sentence, you should probably invest your time in ACLs. That will reduce a lot of the other coding and potential risks. Look into that.

Answer (score 3):

To query messages where the author is not a single author, you can do this:

```
NSString *usernameBlock = [self.blockUser.text]; 
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Message"];
[query whereKey:@"author" notEqualTo:usernameBlock];
[query find...
```

But I think you're aiming to continually block a list of users.  Do that as follows:  add an array column to User called "blockedUsernames" which will contain an array of usernames to block.  (pointers to User would be better, but your Message class is using string usernames as authors, so we'll follow that convention).

Now the query you're looking for to get a user's messages from non-blocked users is...

```
// get messages from non-blocked users
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
NSArray *blockedUsernames = currentUser[@"blockedUsernames"];

PFQuery *innerQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
[innerQuery whereKey:@"username" containedIn:blockedUsernames];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Message"];
[query whereKey:@"author" doesNotMatchQuery:innerQuery];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    // objects will be an array of Messages excluding those authored
    // by users with usernames in blockedUsernames
}];
```

Comment: thank you for the answer above, also how can i show the blocked users in another view controller? we would put the method in the else condition of  `[query findKey...]` ?

Comment: Sure.  See that `innerQuery`?  That finds blocked users.  The code in the answer uses it to exclude messages, but if you run `[innerQuery findObjects...`, you'll get the blocked users.

Comment: i have a class name called `@"Messages"` then within the class i have `@"senderName" @"senderId"` for the user who sends the message and  `@"recipientId"` for user who receives the message, sorry i dont think i mentioned this before

Comment: Sorry, we've traveled too far outside of the norms of the site for me to continue.  It is particularly disappointing to see code from my answer edited into the question as "what I already have".

Comment: Sorry, I want trying to show you if how I used your method was correct I was not at all trying to say it was what I already have I just misplaced it in my question. I have removed it now.

Comment: i have added more to my question, can you please help?

Comment: I would be happy to help, but the question is still missing necessary information.  Please add screen shots from parse data browser that show the message table columns and their types, and the user table columns and their types.  For any type that is array, need to know the type of object held by the array.

Comment: please see the above question with edits you asked for

Comment: i have tried adding `[query whereKey:@"senderName" doesNotMatchQuery:innerQuery];` but it does not get any messages not even from Users that are not blocked also this is the only line that gets users  `[query whereKey:@"recipientIds" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];`

Comment: @smithyy, Thanks.  That is just what's been missing from the various incarnations of this question.

Comment: we are storing recipients as objectIds but we are blocking with usernames. also we are getting all messages related to the users objectId so should we convert the username we enter as objectId? thanks

Comment: I am adding a comprehensive answer now.  It includes changing the model to what I strongly suggest, which is pointer for the sender of a message, an array of pointers to recipients, and an array of pointers to blocked users.  I built a project (including example data model on parse) that demonstrates the concepts at work.

Answer (score 1):

I've built a simple project to illustrate more comprehensive advice.  I strongly urge you to do the same, just to see how the code works uncluttered with other things that have been tried.

In the data model, the key idea is to use pointers, which are very appropriate for sender, recipient lists, and blocked users.  Here's what my project looks like (again - please consider adding a little dummy project to parse so you can see the idea in action.  I'm certain that, if you don't, you won't be able to see how this works)...

**Messages** class contains a *pointer to _User* for the sender and *an array of pointers to _User* for the recipients...

[image]

**User** class contains the normal user stuff and *an array of pointers to _User* for blocked senders.

[image]

Now code.  These functions create users, Sam, Woody and Diane, who will send messages to each other...

```
- (void)createSam:(void (^)(BOOL, NSError *))completion {
    PFUser *sam = [PFUser user];
    sam.username = @"Sam";
    sam.password = @"1234";
    [sam signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:completion];
}

- (void)createWoody:(void (^)(BOOL, NSError *))completion {
    PFUser *woody = [PFUser user];
    woody.username = @"Woody";
    woody.password = @"1234";
    [woody signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:completion];
}

- (void)createDiane:(void (^)(BOOL, NSError *))completion {
    PFUser *diane = [PFUser user];
    diane.username = @"Diane";
    diane.password = @"1234";
    [diane signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:completion];
}

- (void)createUsers:(void (^)(BOOL, NSError *))completion {
    [self createSam:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        [self createWoody:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            [self createDiane:completion];
        }];
    }];
}

// call it like this
[self createUsers:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"created users with success %d, error %@", success, error);
}];
```

This generic method allows a user to block another user...

```
- (void)userNamed:(NSString *)username blockUserNamed:(NSString *)blockedUsername completion:(void (^)(BOOL, NSError *))completion {
    [self getUserNamed:username completion:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        PFUser *user = (PFUser *)object;
        [self getUserNamed:blockedUsername completion:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
            PFUser *blockedUser = (PFUser *)object;
            [user addObject:blockedUser forKey:@"blockedSenders"];
            [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:completion];
        }];
    }];
}

// call it like this
[self userNamed:@"Diane" blockUserNamed:@"Sam" completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"diane blocked sam with success %d, error %@", success, error);
}];
```

This generic method lets a user (usually pass currentUser) send other users a message...

```
- (void)user:(PFUser *)user sendMessage:(NSString *)messageBody toUsersNamed:(NSArray *)recipientNames completion:(void (^)(BOOL, NSError *))completion {

    [self getUsersNamed:recipientNames completion:^(NSArray *recipients, NSError *error) {
        PFObject *message = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Message"];
        message[@"message"] = messageBody;
        message[@"sender"] = user;
        message[@"recipients"] = recipients;
        [message saveInBackgroundWithBlock:completion];
    }];
}

// call it like this
NSString *message = @"Hi Woody, Hi Diane, will you be coming to Cheers tonight?";
NSArray *recipientNames = @[@"Woody", @"Diane"];

PFUser *sam = [PFUser currentUser];
[self user:sam sendMessage:message toUsersNamed:recipientNames completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"sam sent message with success %d, error %@", success, error);
}];
```

Finally, the answer to the question.  Here's a generic method (usually call with currentUser) to fetch messages, excluding blocked messages for a user.  Since we use pointers in the data model, there's no need for a relational query.  (The SDK wants to deal with objects, not object ids, and the relational query I suggested for your old code was there to work around the problem caused by having ids rather than real objects).

```
- (void)fetchMessagesForUser:(PFUser *)user completion:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))completion {
    NSArray *blockedSenders = user[@"blockedSenders"];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Message"];
    [query whereKey:@"recipients" equalTo:user];
    [query whereKey:@"sender" notContainedIn:blockedSenders];
    [query includeKey:@"recipients"];
    [query includeKey:@"sender"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:completion];
}

// call it like this
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
[self fetchMessagesForUser:user completion:^(NSArray *messages, NSError *error) {
    for (PFObject *message in messages) {
        [self logMessage:message];
    }
}];

- (void)logMessage:(PFObject *)message {
    NSMutableArray *recipeintNames = [@[] mutableCopy];
    for (PFUser *recipient in message[@"recipients"]) {
        [recipeintNames addObject:recipient.username];
    }
    NSString *recipientString = [recipeintNames componentsJoinedByString:@","];
    PFUser *sender = message[@"sender"];
    NSLog(@"message to: %@, from: %@... %@", recipientString, sender.username, message[@"message"]);
}
```

For your reference, here's the complete view controller that does all this.  I tested with the code in viewWillAppear (**read that from the bottom of the method up**).  The log shows it working as I think you hope it to...

```
//
//  SmithyyViewController.m

#import "SmithyyViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface SmithyyViewController ()

@end

@implementation SmithyyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)createSam:(void (^)(BOOL, NSError *))completion {
    PFUser *sam = [PFUser user];
    sam.username = @"Sam";
    sam.password = @"1234";
    [sam signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:completion];
}

- (void)createWoody:(void (^)(BOOL, NSError *))completion {
    PFUser *woody = [PFUser user];
    woody.username = @"Woody";
    woody.password = @"1234";
    [woody signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:completion];
}

- (void)createDiane:(void (^)(BOOL, NSError *))completion {
    PFUser *diane = [PFUser user];
    diane.username = @"Diane";
    diane.password = @"1234";
    [diane signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:completion];
}

- (void)getUserNamed:(NSString *)username completion:(void (^)(PFObject *, NSError *))completion {
    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:username];
    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:completion];
}

- (void)getUsersNamed:(NSArray *)usernames completion:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))completion {
    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query whereKey:@"username" containedIn:usernames];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:completion];
}

- (void)createUsers:(void (^)(BOOL, NSError *))completion {
    [self createSam:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        [self createWoody:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            [self createDiane:completion];
        }];
    }];
}

- (void)userNamed:(NSString *)username blockUserNamed:(NSString *)blockedUsername completion:(void (^)(BOOL, NSError *))completion {
    [self getUserNamed:username completion:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        PFUser *user = (PFUser *)object;
        [self getUserNamed:blockedUsername completion:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
            PFUser *blockedUser = (PFUser *)object;
            [user addObject:blockedUser forKey:@"blockedSenders"];
            [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:completion];
        }];
    }];
}

- (void)user:(PFUser *)user sendMessage:(NSString *)messageBody toUsersNamed:(NSArray *)recipientNames completion:(void (^)(BOOL, NSError *))completion {

    [self getUsersNamed:recipientNames completion:^(NSArray *recipients, NSError *error) {
        PFObject *message = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Message"];
        message[@"message"] = messageBody;
        message[@"sender"] = user;
        message[@"recipients"] = recipients;
        [message saveInBackgroundWithBlock:completion];
    }];
}

- (void)fetchMessagesForUser:(PFUser *)user completion:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))completion {
    NSArray *blockedSenders = user[@"blockedSenders"];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Message"];
    [query whereKey:@"recipients" equalTo:user];
    [query whereKey:@"sender" notContainedIn:blockedSenders];
    [query includeKey:@"recipients"];
    [query includeKey:@"sender"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:completion];
}

- (void)logMessage:(PFObject *)message {
    NSMutableArray *recipeintNames = [@[] mutableCopy];
    for (PFUser *recipient in message[@"recipients"]) {
        [recipeintNames addObject:recipient.username];
    }
    NSString *recipientString = [recipeintNames componentsJoinedByString:@","];
    PFUser *sender = message[@"sender"];
    NSLog(@"message to: %@, from: %@... %@", recipientString, sender.username, message[@"message"]);
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // SCROLL TO THE BOTTOM OF THIS METHOD FIRST
    // USE EXAMPLES HERE IN REVERSE ORDER, FROM LAST ONE, TO THE FIRST ONE

// FETCH MESSAGES

//    NSString *username = @"Diane";
//    [self getUserNamed:username completion:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
//        NSLog(@"Logging messages for %@", username);
//        PFUser *user = (PFUser *)object;
//        [self fetchMessagesForUser:user completion:^(NSArray *messages, NSError *error) {
//            for (PFObject *message in messages) {
//                [self logMessage:message];
//            }
//        }];
//    }];


// SEND MESSAGE
//    [self getUserNamed:@"Diane" completion:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
//        
//        NSString *message = @"Hi Woody, I will be the waitress tonight.  See you there.";
//        NSArray *recipientNames = @[@"Woody"];
//        
//        PFUser *sam = (PFUser *)object;
//        [self user:sam sendMessage:message toUsersNamed:recipientNames completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
//            NSLog(@"diane sent message with success %d, error %@", success, error);
//        }];
//        
//    }];

// SEND MESSAGE
//    [self getUserNamed:@"Woody" completion:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
//        
//        NSString *message = @"Hi Diane and Sam, I do all the work at Cheers. So, yes, I will be there";
//        NSArray *recipientNames = @[@"Sam", @"Diane"];
//        
//        PFUser *sam = (PFUser *)object;
//        [self user:sam sendMessage:message toUsersNamed:recipientNames completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
//            NSLog(@"woody sent message with success %d, error %@", success, error);
//        }];
//        
//    }];


// SEND MESSAGE
//    [self getUserNamed:@"Sam" completion:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
//
//        NSString *message = @"Hi Woody, Hi Diane, will you be coming to Cheers tonight?";
//        NSArray *recipientNames = @[@"Woody", @"Diane"];
//
//        PFUser *sam = (PFUser *)object;
//        [self user:sam sendMessage:message toUsersNamed:recipientNames completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
//            NSLog(@"sam sent message with success %d, error %@", success, error);
//        }];
//
//    }];


// BLOCK USER
//    [self userNamed:@"Diane" blockUserNamed:@"Sam" completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
//        NSLog(@"diane blocked sam with success %d, error %@", success, error);
//    }];
//

// BUILD USERS
//    [self createUsers:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
//        NSLog(@"created users with success %d, error %@", success, error);
//    }];
}


@end
```

Comment: thank you so much, i will study it, go over it and implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having to use a compound query or an extra filter each time you access your inbox to remove the blocked users, it would be better to actively prevent those messages from occurring in the first place.

Handling this case with a cloud beforeSave trigger would not affect the responsiveness of your UI through delays caused by a compound query or additional constraints.

You will most likely want to create a new class in Parse called Block/Report/whatever which will contain the user who performed the block along with the blocked user and any other information you may want (details, reason and so on).

Once this is in place, consider that there are two situations in which you need to prevent communication between two users. I could block you or you could block me. In either case, we need to block the communication from occurring.

Since you have an array of recipientIds, create a cloud function called "removeBlockedUsers" or similar which will have the input of your recipients and will output the array with blocked users removed.

To do this, create two queries for each respective case and then or the queries together in a compound query. In the response of the query, filter out the results (the blocked users) from the recipient array.

Now whenever you need to make sure blocked users are handled, in a beforeSave trigger (or however else you prefer) you can call the removeBlockedUsers cloud function.

Cheers, Russell

Comment: thanks, how can i go about implementing this? where would i add the cloud code?

Comment: Check out [Cloud Code Getting Started](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code). Cloud code is incredibly powerful and should be where the majority of your app logic occurs.

Comment: is there not an easier way we could do it in code? i have added more to the question above. thanks

Comment: Of course there is an easier way to do it in code, that would be similar to the first answer provided. I gave my answer as an alternative approach which would be more extensible toward future changes. You asked for the best way to do this, and the best practices in app development are to abstract as much logic away from the client as possible. I think you might want to reference some more tutorials to get a better idea of how you should be structuring your app.